# How to retrieve data from a webpage and show it in xaml continuously in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm extremely new to develop WP8 in C#. I'm trying to write a simple app which will fetch data from a web page, and then update a `TextBlock` continuously, possibly every second.

Currently, I am able to fetch data from the web page, but cannot update the `TextBlock`, even though I have used `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The `TextBlock` is only updated once when the application started.

The cs file of MachineData:

```
public class MachineData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string CurrentValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentValue");
        }
    }
    private string _currentValue;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that I used for fetching data:

```
foreach (MachineData md in Items)
{
    var wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        string data = (string)e.Result;
        md.CurrentValue = data; // Update the value of machine
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(address));
    };
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(address));
}
```

The xaml snippet:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentValue}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: U might need to run this 'md.CurrentValue = data; // Update the value of machine' in UI thread

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using some list like control, such as `ListBox`, `GridView`, etc...

What you need to do is bind your `Items` to `ItemSource` to the control then you'll get an update.

I don't currently see how you are binding the `MachineData` to a control so that might be my first guess is to why it doesn't work for you.

Here is some working code.

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentValue}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <Button Click="Button_Click">click</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    List<MachineData> Items = new List<MachineData>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Application.Current.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = false;
        }

        Items.Add(new MachineData());

        MyListBox.ItemsSource = Items;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MachineData md in Items)
        {
            md.CurrentValue = "Update Text";
        }
    }
}
```

Here, if you press the button, the `MachineData` is set with "Update Text" and you should see the text update.